# Set a field to the value of another field

Tags: sql

Is there an SQL statement that I could run that says to set a field to the value of another field? So I want to set field A to the same value that is in field b?

Comment: `UPDATE tab SET colA = colB`

Comment: This is a pretty basic `update` statement.

Comment: _Column_, not field...